# Constructor for Struct with Private Members

Tags: c++, struct, c++11, private-members

Consider the following code:

```
class A
{
private:
    struct B { private: int i; friend class A; };

public:
    static void foo1()
    {
        B b;
        b.i = 0;
    }

    static void foo2()
    {
        B b = {0};
    }
};
```

Why does **foo1** work but not **foo2**? Is not the struct initializer constructor visible for class A? Is there anyway to make this work in C++11?

(Note, removing the private makes foo2 working.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Why does `foo1` work but not `foo2`? Is not the struct initializer constructor visible for class `A`?**

```
B b = {0};
```

Does not work because `B` is not an **Aggregate**. And it is not an Aggregate because it has an non-static private data member. If you remove the private specifier, `B` becomes an Aggregate and hence can be initialized in this manner.

---

**C++03 Standard 8.5.1 Aggregates**
**Para 7:**

> If there are fewer initializers in the list than there are members in the aggregate, then each member not explicitly initialized shall be value-initialized (8.5). 
>   [Example:
>
> ```
>  struct S { int a; char* b; int c; };
>  S ss = { 1, "asdf" };
> ```
>
> initializes `ss.a` with `1`, `ss.b` with `"asdf"`, and `ss.c` with the value of an expression of the form `int()`, that is,`0`. ]

**C++03 standard 8.5.1 §1**:

> An aggregate is an array or a class (clause 9) with no user-declared 
>   constructors (12.1), **no private or protected non-static data members** (clause 11),
>   no base classes (clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3).